# Does anyone know how to debug android applications on a tablet from an Amazon workspace?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, amazon-workspaces

I am using an amazon work space to code in and wanted to debug my application. I cant spin up an emulator in a vm so I was wondering if anyone has had any success getting a tablet to connect to android studio that is in an amazon workspace.